# Help Optimising SQL query

Tags: sql, optimization, select

I have a huge query which has gradually grown over the years and all iv done is add sub procedures to it to satisfy the growth. the issue im having now is this query takes about 3 minutes to run. can some one help me with optimising this query

```
SELECT ENTRY_1.REP_CODE,CONTACT_1.NAME,
       (select sum((d2.total_goods-d2.total_cost)*et2.sign) 
        from detail d2 
        join entry e2 on d2.entry_id=e2.entry_id 
        join entry_type et2 on et2.entry_type=e2.entry_type 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where ((d2.detail_type = 'O' and d2.charged_qty<d2.qty 
        and d2.nocharge_qty=0) 
        or (d2.detail_type = 'N' and e2.entry_type in('SINV','SCRN','DREC','DSRF'))
        or (( e2.entry_type = 'SJIN' ) and ( d2.total_goods = 0 ))) 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
        and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num)) MTD_GP,
    -- get the month to date sales  
       (select sum((d2.total_goods)*et2.sign) 
        from detail d2 
        join entry e2 on d2.entry_id=e2.entry_id 
        join entry_type et2 on et2.entry_type=e2.entry_type 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where ((d2.detail_type = 'O' and d2.charged_qty<d2.qty 
        and d2.nocharge_qty=0) 
        or (d2.detail_type = 'N' and e2.entry_type in('SINV','SCRN','DREC','DSRF'))
        or (( e2.entry_type = 'SJIN' ) and ( d2.total_goods = 0 ))) 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
        and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num)) MTD_SALES,
    -- 
       (select sum((d2.total_goods-d2.total_cost)*et2.sign) 
        from detail d2 
        join entry e2 on d2.entry_id=e2.entry_id 
        join entry_type et2 on et2.entry_type=e2.entry_type 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where (d2.detail_type = 'O' and d2.charged_qty<d2.qty and d2.nocharge_qty=0) 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
        and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num)) ORD_GP,

       (select sum((d2.total_goods)*et2.sign) 
        from detail d2 
        join entry e2 on d2.entry_id=e2.entry_id 
        join entry_type et2 on et2.entry_type=e2.entry_type 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where (d2.detail_type = 'O' and d2.charged_qty<d2.qty and d2.nocharge_qty=0) 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
        and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num)) ORD_SALE,

       (select sum((d2.total_goods-d2.total_cost)*et2.sign) 
        from detail d2 
        join entry e2 on d2.entry_id=e2.entry_id 
        join entry_type et2 on et2.entry_type=e2.entry_type 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where d2.detail_type = 'N' and e2.entry_type in('SINV','SCRN','DREC','DSRF') 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
        and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num)) INV_GP,

       (select sum((d2.total_goods)*et2.sign) 
        from detail d2 
        join entry e2 on d2.entry_id=e2.entry_id 
        join entry_type et2 on et2.entry_type=e2.entry_type 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where d2.detail_type = 'N' and e2.entry_type in('SINV','SCRN','DREC','DSRF') 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
        and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num)) INV_SALE,

       (select sum((d2.total_goods-d2.total_cost)*et2.sign) 
        from detail d2 
        join entry e2 on d2.entry_id=e2.entry_id 
        join entry_type et2 on et2.entry_type=e2.entry_type 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where ( e2.entry_type = 'SJIN' ) and ( d2.total_goods = 0 ) 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
        and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num)) EXPEND,

       (select count(distinct e2.trader_id) 
        from entry e2 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where e2.entry_type in('SORD','SINV','DREC') 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
        and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num)) MTD_PUR,

       (select count(distinct e2.our_reference) 
        from entry e2 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where e2.entry_type in('SORD') and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
        and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num)) MTD_ORD,

    (select sum((d1.total_goods-d1.total_cost)*et.sign) 
        from detail d1 
        join entry e1 on d1.entry_id=e1.entry_id 
        join entry_type et on et.entry_type=e1.entry_type 
        left outer join detail d2 on d2.detail_id=d1.link_detail_id 
        join rep r2 on e1.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where ((d1.detail_type = 'O' and d1.charged_qty<d1.qty and d1.nocharge_qty=0 and e1.entry_type in ('SORD','SRTN') 
        and e1.our_reference not like 'AUTO%') 
        or (d1.detail_type = 'N' and e1.entry_type in('SCRN','DREC','DSRF'))
        or (( e1.entry_type = 'SJIN' ) and ( d1.total_goods = 0 ))
        or(( d1.DETAIL_TYPE = 'N' ) and ( e1.ENTRY_TYPE = 'SINV' ) and ( e1.TAXPOINT_DATE = CURRENT_DATE ) and ( d2.DETAIL_TYPE = 'A' ))) 
        and e1.taxpoint_date=current_date 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id) DAILY_GP,
    (select count(*) 
        from entry e2 
        join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where e2.entry_type='SORD' 
        and  e2.taxpoint_date=current_date 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id) NUM_ORDS,
    (select count(tn.note) 
        from trader_notes tn join trader t on tn.trader_id=t.trader_id  
        join rep r2 on t.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
        join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
        where tn.created between current_date 
        and (current_date+1) 
        and tn.note_type in ('N','S','G') 
        and tn.note is not null 
        and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id) NOTES
FROM ENTRY ENTRY_1 INNER JOIN REP REP_1 ON
     (REP_1.REP_CODE = ENTRY_1.REP_CODE)
      INNER JOIN CONTACT CONTACT_1 ON
     (CONTACT_1.CONTACT_ID = REP_1.CONTACT_ID)
WHERE ( ENTRY_1.ENTRY_TYPE = 'SJOB' )
       AND ( ENTRY_1.AGE = 0 )
```

as you can see both these sub procedures are the same, the only difference is the sum on the select statement. is there a way in which I can run only one of the sub procedures to find the sum ?

**Iv shown the full query, please can some one help me out ?**

Comment: Which database... SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc...

Comment: Additionally, just to confirm from the major cluster of join / sub-join, is the "Entry_ID" an auto-increment key in the Entry table, and that is the "key" that directly joins your "Detail" table (not withstanding your other "where" clauses to qualify specific details)... but just the JOIN basis itself?

Comment: Can you please look at my answer (question really) to provide more specific detail clarification between Entry and Detail table... Too long for simple comments here...

Comment: When a sale is made the overall deatils for that sale is stored in the ENTRY table. this is then linked to the DETAIL table which stores data on each item in that sale. the entry table is also linked to the rep table which stored which sales rep made that entry.

Comment: to answer to question DRapp the entry ID is unique identifier which is linked to the detail table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some review, I think I have something for you to give a shot... You may have to adjust it some, but hopefully takes a LOT of the confusion OUT for you.  The biggest killer of the query is how you have COUNT(DISTINCT) values that are NOT based on the primary criteria of qualified entries...

That being said, looking at all your joins, you are joining from the entry table to a rep table, and from rep to a contact table.  If the rep ID always points to a contact to get the same "ID", then it appears the rep code is like a shortcut to the actual "contact_id" in the salesperson contact table.  That said, no need to JOIN TO the Rep table OR the Contact table.  The sales header has the "REP_CODE", so this can eliminate all the joins and groupings (unless you correct me otherwise).

Next.  I have TWO Preliminary queries starting at the inner-most.   Your original OUTERMOST query was to have only entry IDs based on an entry type of "SJOB" and Age = 0.  So, my "PQ1" (pre query 1) will get ONLY those entries that qualify that condition and get the rep's code, contact ID and name, and the corresponding year/periods.  This is all DISTINCT.

This result is then joined to the entry table (e2 alias) based on the same rep, year and period (hence eliminating a bunch of other join/where's elsewhere).  This is then joining the e2 to the detail table to get all items.  This is the start of the "PQ2" (pre query 2).

Since I received distinct for a given contact rep, year and period, it looks like you are getting an overall activity for anyone in the main PQ1 query and looking at their OVERALL sales activity within same qualified year / period.

The where clause you had for getting your Gross, Sales and Invoiced amounts had 3 condition.  This is the main "WHERE" clause of the PreQuery 2 condition.  In the fields list, since they all basically had the same qualifying criteria, I just added

SUM( case When ... ) as MTD_GP,
sum( case when ... ) as MTD_Sales,
sum() for Order_GP and Order_Sales (based on the FIRST Where portion)
sum() for INVOICED_GP and INVOICED_Sales (based on the SECOND Where portion)
sum() for EXPEND (based on the THIRD part of the where portion)

Once I got that complete, and all rolled-up, grouped by the given rep, period, year, I took THAT result as a basis to finish all your OTHER count distinct(), count(*), etc entries.  Again, since I know I already have it broken down to a given Rep, I can re-query to the entry 2 table again in a similar fashion.

Hope this greatly clarifies what I perceive your query of trying to get accomplished and jump-starts you into a better / final solution.

From your Joins, it appears your "Rep table" has a contact ID in which multiple reps can all point to a single "contact".  No need to explicitly JOIN to contact just for the Contact ID that already exists IN the Rep Table... So you can simplify the join to just the entry table to the Rep table and get the contact ID.

```
select
      PQ2.Rep_Code,
      PQ2.Contact_ID,
      PQ2.Name,
      PQ2.Year_Num,
      PQ2.Period_Num,
      PQ2.MTD_GP,
      PQ2.MTD_SALES,
      PQ2.ORD_GP,
      PQ2.ORD_SALE,
      PQ2.INV_GP,
      PQ2.INV_SALE,
      PQ2.EXPEND,
      ( select count(distinct e2.trader_id) 
           from entry e2
           where  e2.rep_code = PQ2.Rep_Code
              and e2.Year_Num = PQ2.Year_Num
              and e2.Period_Num = PQ2.Period_Num 
              and e2.entry_type in ('SORD','SINV','DREC') ) MTD_PUR,

      ( select count(distinct e2.trader_id) 
           from entry e2
           where  e2.rep_code = PQ2.Rep_Code
              and e2.Year_Num = PQ2.Year_Num
              and e2.Period_Num = PQ2.Period_Num 
              and e2.entry_type = 'SORD' ) MTD_ORD,

      ( select count(*)
           from entry e2 
           where e2.rep_code = PQ2.Rep_Code
             and e2.entry_type='SORD' 
             and e2.taxpoint_date = current_date ) NUM_ORDS,


      ( select count(tn.note)
           from trader_notes tn 
               join trader t on tn.trader_id = t.trader_id
                            AND t.rep_code = PQ2.Rep_Code
           where 
                  tn.created between current_date and (current_date + 1) 
              and tn.note_type in ('N','S','G') 
              and tn.note is not null ) NOTES,

      ( select 
              sum( ( d3.total_goods - d3.total_cost) * et3.sign) 
           from
              entry e3
                 join detail d3 on e3.entry_id = d3.entry_id
                    left join detail dLink on d3.link_detail_id = dLink.detail_id
                 join entry_type et3 on e3.entry_type = et3.entry_type
           where 
                  PQ2.Rep_Code = e3.Rep_Code
              AND e3.taxpoint_date = current_date 
              AND (  (     d3.detail_type = 'O' 
                       and d3.charged_qty < d3.qty 
                       and d3.nocharge_qty = 0 
                       and e3.entry_type in ('SORD','SRTN') 
                       and e3.our_reference not like 'AUTO%'
                     ) 
                  or (     d3.detail_type = 'N' 
                        and e3.entry_type in ('SCRN','DREC','DSRF')
                      )
                  or (      e3.entry_type = 'SJIN'
                        and d3.total_goods = 0
                     )
                  or (     d3.DETAIL_TYPE = 'N'
                       and e3.ENTRY_TYPE = 'SINV'
                       and e3.TAXPOINT_DATE = CURRENT_DATE
                       and dLink.DETAIL_TYPE = 'A'
                     )
                 ) 
             ) DAILY_GP

   FROM
      ( select 
              PQ1.Rep_Code,
              PQ1.Contact_ID,
              PQ1.Name,
              PQ1.Year_Num,
              PQ1.Period_Num,

              sum( (d2.Total_Goods - d2.Total_Cost ) * et2.Sign ) as MTD_GP,

              sum( d2.Total_Goods * et2.Sign ) as MTD_SALES,

              sum( case when d2.detail_type = 'O' 
                         and d2.charged_qty < d2.qty 
                         and d2.nocharge_qty = 0 
                        then (d2.total_goods - d2.total_cost) * et2.sign
                        else 0 end ) ORD_GP,

              sum( case when d2.detail_type = 'O' 
                         and d2.charged_qty < d2.qty 
                         and d2.nocharge_qty = 0 
                        then (d2.total_goods * et2.sign )
                        else 0 end ) ORD_SALE,

              sum( case when d2.detail_type = 'N' 
                         and e2.entry_type in('SINV','SCRN','DREC','DSRF')
                        then (d2.total_goods - d2.total_cost) * et2.sign
                        else 0 end ) INV_GP,

              sum( case when d2.detail_type = 'N' 
                         and e2.entry_type in('SINV','SCRN','DREC','DSRF')
                        then (d2.total_goods * et2.sign )
                        else 0 end ) INV_SALE,

              sum( case when e2.entry_type = 'SJIN'
                         and d2.total_goods = 0
                        then (d2.total_goods - d2.total_cost) * et2.sign
                        else 0 end ) EXPEND

           FROM
              ( select distinct
                      r1.rep_code,
                      r1.contact_id,
                      c1.Name,
                      e1.year_num,
                      e1.period_num
                   from
                      entry e1
                         join rep r1 ON e1.rep_code = r1.rep_code
                            join contact c1 on r1.contact_id = c1.contact_id
                   where
                          e1.entry_type = 'SJOB'
                      and e1.age = 0 ) PQ1

                JOIN entry e2 on PQ1.rep_code = e2.rep_code
                             AND PQ1.Year_Num = e2.Year_Num
                             AND PQ1.Period_Num = e2.Period_Num
                   JOIN Detail d2 on e2.Entry_ID = d2.Entry_ID
                   JOIN Entry_Type et2 on e2.entry_type = et2.entry_type
            WHERE    
                 (     d2.detail_type = 'O' 
                   and d2.charged_qty < d2.qty 
                   and d2.nocharge_qty = 0  ) 

               or (    d2.detail_type = 'N' 
                   and e2.entry_type in('SINV','SCRN','DREC','DSRF') )

               or (    e2.entry_type = 'SJIN'
                   and d2.total_goods = 0 )

           GROUP BY
              PQ1.Rep_Code,
              PQ1.Contact_ID,
              PQ1.Name,
              PQ1.Year_Num,
              PQ1.Period_Num ) as PQ2
```

Comment: When a sale is made the overall deatils for that sale is stored in the ENTRY table. this is then linked to the DETAIL table which stores data on each item in that sale. the entry table is also linked to the rep table which stored which sales rep made that entry.
to answer to question DRapp the entry ID is unique identifier which is linked to the detail table

Comment: @c11ada, posted complex answer, couldn't test (obviously) but clarified extensively how/what is going on for you.

Comment: i get the following error, any ideas why this may be, im using Interbase ibconsole. can this have a different sytax ?

Error at line 1
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 75, char 7
select

Comment: @c11ada, because of the nested select from select from select, it might be choking on that.  What I would do is try one select at a time... Start with the inner-most and work your way out. The query itself is pretty standard of syntax.  Try with the "PQ1" first, then up-to and including the "PQ2", then try the full based on any adjustments.  Let me know if anything else kicks in early on the testing...

Comment: @c11ada, since you accepted the answer, two curious questions... How is the final performance, and what was the syntax it apparently choked on so I can fix it in this answer...

Answer (score 5):

sure - something like this:

```
SELECT ENTRY_1.AGE, ENTRY_1.REP_CODE,CONTACT_1.NAME, ENTRY_1.GOODS,
           sum((d2.total_goods-d2.total_cost)*et2.sign) 
           , sum((d2.total_goods)*et2.sign) 
.
.
. CODE TAKEN OUT
.
.
    FROM 
            detail d2 
            join entry e2 on d2.entry_id=e2.entry_id 
            join entry_type et2 on et2.entry_type=e2.entry_type 
            join rep r2 on e2.rep_code=r2.rep_code 
            join contact c2 on r2.contact_id=c2.contact_id 
            where ((d2.detail_type = 'O' and d2.charged_qty<d2.qty 
            and d2.nocharge_qty=0) 
            or (d2.detail_type = 'N' and e2.entry_type in('SINV','SCRN','DREC','DSRF'))
            or (( e2.entry_type = 'SJIN' ) and ( d2.total_goods = 0 ))) 
            and c2.contact_id=contact_1.contact_id 
            and (e2.year_num=entry_1.year_num and e2.period_num=entry_1.period_num))      MTD_GP
, ENTRY ENTRY_1 INNER JOIN REP REP_1 ON
         (REP_1.REP_CODE = ENTRY_1.REP_CODE)
          INNER JOIN CONTACT CONTACT_1 ON
         (CONTACT_1.CONTACT_ID = REP_1.CONTACT_ID)
    WHERE ( ENTRY_1.ENTRY_TYPE = 'SJOB' )
           AND ( ENTRY_1.AGE = 0 )
```

of course the idea is that you move the joins down below - take them out of the SELECT clause and put them (once) into the FROM and WHERE clauses.  - the cut and paste i did is not really right, but you get the idea  (also you didnt give a complete query to actually use as a basis)

Comment: Great answer!  For perspective it is a good idea to explain however why the original query performed so poorly.  The two subqueries were unnecessary, but also in the select statement itself, meaning that both were getting executed for every single row that returns in the original query.

Comment: Randy... iv updated the SQL query above, please could you advice me on how i would optimise that query.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you should not use  correlated subqueries for any query where the data set will eventually be large as they behave like cursors and run row-by-row. You should use joins to tables or derived tables instead.

This is true for SQl Server I know, it may be differnt in other databases.